# Trying to get some double output "ZA YB"

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

Okay, next problem. I need to output: ZA  YB  XC  WD  VE  UF  TG  SH  RI  QJ.
I have:

```
public static void outputEight()
{
    System.out.println(" ");
    String zQ = "Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
        for(int alphz=zQ.length()-1; alphz>=0; alphz--)
        {
            for(char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'L'; alph++)
            {
                System.out.print(zQ.charAt(alphz) + alph);
                if(alph== 'L')
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

        }
}
```

What should I do instead to put me on the right track?

Comment: ah... what's with this code? That's not what they had in mind when they asked you to output Q to Z. the variable zQ is not the right idea.

Comment: What you do next is learn that letters are consecutive in ASCII/Unicode, i.e. `B` immediately follows `A`, and that Java treats characters as numbers, so you can *calculate* a letter, e.g. if `i = 3` and you do `(char)('A' + i)`, the result is `'D'`. So, iterate `i` from 0 to 9, calculate first letter as `'Z' - i` and second letter as `'A' + i`, and build string with those two letters.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many solutions to your problem:

```
public static void outputEight()
{
    String[] zQ = "Q R S T U V W X Y Z".split(" ");
    for (int alphz=zQ.length - 1 ; alphz >= 0 ; alphz--) {
      System.out.println(zQ[alphz] + (char)('A' + zQ.length-1-alphz));
    }
}
```

Here I make an array of appropriate chars from 'Q' to 'Z', using split function. Then I iterate its indexes in opposite order, concatenating appropriate char from 'A' to 'J'.

Comment: Andreas's solution is better in my opinion :) but ya , it works

Comment: Thank you. This helped immensely

Comment: @DPabst [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes use of your for(char alph...) loop:

```
    for(char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'J'; alph++)
    {
        System.out.print((char)('Z'-alph+'A'));
        System.out.print(alph);
        if(alph == 'J') {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

Another way using Java 8 streams:

```
    System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'J')
            .mapToObj(c -> new char[]{(char)('Z'-c+'A'),(char)c})
            .map(String::new)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```